# Swift - How can you add a banner to the screen while your app is in the background mode?

Tags: ios, swift, background, banner

I am working on an application where I want the user to know it is on in the background mode via  one of those banners like when you are using Uber or Alarm Cycle. 
I know if you use location it will add it but I do not want to do it (probably would get rejected too).

Is there a way to add this banner?

Comment: You can add a banner to your screen when the App is going to enter background. You can do that in AppDelegate's "applicationWillEnterForeground". Does that make sense??

Comment: I want to add the banner when my app is going into the background not when it is entering the foreground

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i meant "applicationDidEnterBackground"

Answer (score 0):

**1. Open your AppDelegate.swift file**

**2. Register your app with iOS so that it's able send the user notifications inside of applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    registerForNotifications()
    return true
}

func registerForNotifications() {
    // Register for notification: This will prompt for the user's consent to receive notifications from this app.
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in

    }
}
```

**3. Fill in the content and time you want the notification to go off and save it as a UNNotificationRequest. (I made it go off one second after the notification is added.)**

```
func createBackgroundNotificationRequest() -> UNNotificationRequest {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Entered Background Mode"
    content.subtitle = "Just so you are aware."
    content.body = "We'll be waiting for you back in the app"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "BackgroundNotification", content: content, trigger: UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false))

    return request
}
```

**4. Add the request to UNUserNotificationCenter.current() inside of applicationDidEnterBackground state**

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    let notificationRequest = createBackgroundNotificationRequest()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notificationRequest, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

[Here's a demo project I made performing the task you want.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g2uu6k7i7oe0fn1/AADThdQraVVCxWXDh0irTmIOa?dl=0)

Just open the app, authorize notifications, then hit the home button and the background notification should trigger.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. This gives the user a notification. I want a sustained banner that is shown while the app is in the background.